# Why my vsftp service can't start?

Tags: ftp

Here is my /etc/vsftpd.conf .

```
listen=on
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
local_root=/home/ftp
anon_root=/home/ftp
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
```

In the console,

```
service vsftpd start
root@pengsir:/home/debian8# service vsftpd status
● vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2015-10-17 15:37:34 HKT; 4s ago
  Process: 3060 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 3057 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/vsftpd/empty (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3060 (code=exited, status=2)

Oct 17 15:37:34 pengsir systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: main process exited, co...NT
Oct 17 15:37:34 pengsir systemd[1]: Unit vsftpd.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Why the vsftp service can't start?

Comment: What does the `/var/log/vsftpd.log` say?

Comment: cat /var/log/vsftpd.log

Comment: nothing in the output!!

Comment: Then start it manually, `/usr/sbin/vsftpd` .

Comment: Thanks @MariusMatutiae. after running `sudo /usr/sbin/vsftpd` it gave me the specific argument that it couldn't recognize. I had a typo in the argument name.

Answer (score 5):

When I used `sudo /usr/sbin/vsftpd`, it gave

```
500 OOPS: unrecognised variable in config file: allow_ftpd_full_access.
```

Once I commented that line, `vsftpd` started.

Comment: After trying to find the reason for an INVALIDARGUMENT and not finding it logged anywhere, nor finding a solution on how to point out syntax or other issues within the vsftpd.conf setup, your solution saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

first remove the vsftpd packages using these commands.

1 : sudo apt-get remove vsftpd
2 : sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove vsftpd
3 : sudo apt-get purge vsftpd
4 : sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove vsftpd

After This Process Succesfully done.now you can install it again using this command

sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
service vsftpd status